# Creating one of two sessions php

Tags: php, session, authentication

Im trying to create two different sessions. One for the admin, the other for normal users. If SQL returns admin_role as 1 = admin. If admin_role as 0 = user.

I have session_start() in the beginning of the document via include('connection.php'). When I press submit on my login form nothing really happens as for now.

```
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"])){
    $error = "Fill in both fields!";
} else {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    // To protect from MySQL injection
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);

    // Check username and password from database
    $sql = "SELECT admin_role FROM user WHERE user_name='$username' AND user_password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    $admin_role = $row['admin_role'];

    // If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
    // Otherwise echo error.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        if($admin_role == 1){
            $_SESSION['admin'];
            header("location: logged-in.php");
        }
        if($admin_role == 0){
            $_SESSION['username'];
            header("location: logged-in.php");
        }

    } else {
        $error = "Wrong credentials";
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you store your passwords as plain text. don't do that, store hashes instead.

Comment: Noted. Anything regarding the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing really happens"? By using `$_SESSION['admin'];` you don't create a session, you just try to access value under `admin` key within `$_SESSION` array. You should rather go for `$_SESSION['admin']=1` or `$_SESSION['type'] = 'admin'`

Comment: Try `echo $admin_role` to see what it returns

Comment: @michaJlS When i press the submit button on the login form "nothing happens" as in no errors and the script takes me nowhere. I'm new to sessions so I don't really understand your suggestions there.

Comment: What @michaJlS said. You create a session with some values. And those values entitle to admin status or not. Your pages and processes have to check the user level (1, 2, 3, admin, whatever) from the session variable and allow or deny specific actions. (At this point, regarding admin status, nothing visible happens. User is directed to logged-in-page or `$error` variable is created.)

Comment: You never retrieve your row/s from the mysql result.  Therefore $admin_role will evaluate to null.

Comment: Can we see your form?

Comment: @Progrock the form is nothing fancy. Inputs with ids "username" and "password" which posts to login.php which contain the code above. 
How should I retrieve my row?

Comment: And you have method="POST" in your form? With the form inputs with 'names': username and password?

Comment: @Progrock Correct. The form itself is not an issue. It works if i use the username as a session, things went south when trying to create different sessions for different users based on the admin_role row.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`, but I'd expect at least a redirect already, as $admin_role currently evaluates to null.  So ($admin_role == 0) will evaluate to true.  Which to me indicates that you are not getting a result set.  Which could be a bad query, or invalid parameters.  Other omissions as said are there is no assignment to your session key, and no call to `session_start`.